# Adb install failed invalid location

Tags: android, adb

I uninstalled system app, Gallery2(com.android.gallery3d) from my phone and tried installing the app as normal app using

```
adb install -r /home/risingup/CM12.1/out/target/product/bacon/system/app/Gallery2/Gallery2.apk
```

I get the error:

```
293 KB/s (5764099 bytes in 19.208s)pkg: /data/local/tmp/Gallery2.apk
```

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION]

I tried changing permissions of `/data/local/tmp` folder but still same error. Please help.

```
chmod 777 /data /data/local /data/local/tmp
```

which gave

```
root@A0001:/ # ls -ld data data/local data/local/tmp 
drwxrwxrwx system   system            2015-08-26 23:20 data
drwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-08-26 14:33 local
drwxrwxrwx shell    shell             2015-08-27 00:12 tmp
```

Phone Info:
Model : One Plus One (A0001)
Android Version: 5.1.1
OS : Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: I think there's a preferred install location that can be declared in the manifest which says to only install in the system, which could explain the error. You could probably push the apk to the device then install from shell as super user. Or just use shell to copy it to the `/data` app folder, reboot the device, and then it'll probably show in the app list. You might get random problems with the app though, if any system-only apis are used in the gallery. I'm kinda guessing though. It's been a LONG time since I've worked on Android stuff.

Comment: When I push apk to system and reboot. It works. I don't want to actually reboot my phone everytime when I make changes to code and push the apk . Hence, trying to install as user app. Also, there is no installLocation mentioned in Manifest

Comment: @SjNerd Did you resolve this?